# Decide disjunctions in sort Prop

Tags: coq

I am interested in the probably false lemma :

```
Lemma decideOr : forall (P Q : Prop),
    (P \/ Q) -> {P} + {Q}.
```

that asserts we can algorithmically decide any proof of an `or` in sort `Prop`. Of course, Coq does not let us `destruct` the input to extract it in sort `Set`. However, a proof of `P \/ Q` is a lambda-term that Coq accepts to print, so external tools can process it.

First question : can this lambda-term be decided outside of Coq (assuming the term uses no axioms, only plain Coq) ? It might be, because the rules of constructive logic demand that all disjunctions be explicitely chosen, without cheating by a proof by contradiction. So can we code a parser of Coq proof terms, and try to decide whether the first or the second operand of the `or` was proved ? If the term starts with `or_introl` or `or_intror` we are done. So I guess the problems are when the term is a lambda-application. But then Coq terms are strongly normalizing, so we reduce it to a normal form and it seems it will start with either `or_introl` or `or_intror`.

Second question : if this problem can be decided outside of Coq, what prevents us from internalizing it within Coq, ie proving lemma `decideOr` above ?

Comment: Hi @V. Semeria, I am a bit short on time today, but the quick answer to your last question is that there exists a model where `decideOr` is false; thus by consistency, it is not provable.

Comment: What do you mean by "can this lambda-term be decided outside of Coq"?

Comment: @ArthurAzevedoDeAmorim Coding a parser of Coq terms that tells left or right when you give it a proof of an `or` in Prop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## First question

Yes, you can write a program that takes as input a Coq proof of `A \/ B` and outputs `true` or `false` depending on which side was used to prove the disjunction.  Indeed, if you write

```
Compute P.
```

in Coq, where `P : A \/ B`, Coq will normalize the proof `P` and print which constructor was used.  This will not work if `P` uses proofs that end in `Qed` (because those are not unfolded by the evaluator), but in principle it is possible to replace `Qed` by `Defined` everywhere and make it work.

## Second question

What prevents us from proving `decideOr` is that the designers of Coq wanted to have a type of propositions that supports the excluded middle (using an axiom) while allowing programs to execute.  If `decideOr` were a theorem *and* we wanted to use the excluded middle (`classical : forall A : Prop, A \/ ~ A`), it would not be possible to execute programs that branch on the result of `decideOr (classical A)`.  This does not mean that `decideOr` is false: it is perfectly possible to admit it as an axiom. There is a difference between not being provable ("there does not exist a proof of `A`") and being refutable ("there exists a proof of `~ A`").

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to admit as axioms simultaneously `decideOr` and the excluded middle ? I hear some combinations of axioms trigger the Hurkens paradox and inconsistencies. In what conditions can we take `decideOr` as an axiom ?

Comment: You can do even better. The standard library has the strong excluded middle as an axiom `forall A, {A} + {~A}`.

Comment: There is no good general rule for knowing when the strong excluded middle can be assumed. It's known to be inconsistent with the "impredicative set" option and with the univalence axiom, but consistent with functional and propositional extensionality. It also implies the axiom of choice, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: FYI I finally found this strong excluded middle in the standard lib. In file ClassicalDescription.v, it is called excluded_middle_informative.